# firebase auto logins in even when i set remember me to false

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

As soon as I click the button it will try and log me in and I haven't even made a call to : `auth.login('password', {  email: email,  password:password,rememberMe: false});`  yet...

I use the `rememberme: false` setting and it still does the same thing. Why does it try to log me in automatically without calling `auth.login`?

```
 var baseRef = new Firebase("https://XXX.firebaseIO.com");

    $("button").click(function(){
    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(baseRef, function(error, user) {
      if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
      } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('Logged in -- > User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);               
      } else {
           console.log('Userlogged out ');
        // user is logged out
      }
    });             
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for email/password](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html) have this blurb:

> rememberMe: (boolean) Override default session length (browser session) to be 30 days.

So to clarify a bit, setting `rememberMe: false` (which is the default behavior) would not prevent saving the login between page loads, but instead causes the token to be invalidated after the current browser session is closed. Inversely, setting this to `true` preserves the token for 30 days.